# Paper button hover event

Tags: polymer-1.0, dart-polymer

I wanted to fire some additional information when a Paper button is hovered, and not necessarily pressed.  I am currently aware of:  `on-tap="myFunc"` when defining the function, but when looking at the Polymer docs, I did not really see anything about *on-hover*.  I could be looking in the wrong place

I noticed that Paper Button is-a *HtmlElement* when looking at the source of the paper-button.  I just cant really see where all of the event handlers are being set.

Is there an on-hover?  If so, where it is at?  Kid of tedious with there not being markup intellisense.

I was inspecting the Paper Button source, as well as looking into: https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-button?view=demo:demo/index.html&active=paper-button but most of that is stylizing based and not really fired events from an on-hover

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can bind to native browser events, no need for every element to dispatch each event.

> // this handler will be executed only once when the cursor moves over the unordered list

```
<paper-button on-mouseenter="doSomething">
```

> // this handler will be executed every time the cursor is moved over a different list item

```
<paper-button on-mouseover="doSomething">
```

See also https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/Events/mouseover

Comment: this works.  I was thinking that since **tap** is a polymer thing, that there would be another associated variant for hover.   Seems like, i just do `on-X` just like regular markup / javascript to get the fire to occur.

Comment: Jup, just like regular markup. `tap` is from [Polymer gestures](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/events.html#gestures) which tries to create a common set of events that work on different devices (desktop, phone, tablet, ...), but on touch-devices there is nothing like hover anyway, therefore there are no other events than the ones provided by the browser.

Comment: why are there no curly brackets needed ?
<paper-button on-mouseenter="{{doSomething}}">

Comment: Curly braces are only for property binding. The `on-` already indicates Polymer event binding, therefore no additional curly braces required.

Comment: Curly braces are only for property binding. The `on-` already indicates Polymer event binding, therefore no additional curly braces required.